# Synergy Virtual Mouse Cursor

Tags: mouse, synergy

I am using [Synergy](https://github.com/symless/synergy) version 1.4.6 (Debian - Client) and 1.4.5 (Windows - Host).

Keyboard and mouse are attached to the host system. I want to use the client without any mouse or keyboard connected. However as soon as I unplug the client's mouse and reset synergy the mouse cursor disappears on the host.

`Synergy` is still functioning well, however without showing any mouse cursor on host side.

Is it possible to have no mouse attached to the client host and still see a mouse cursor? Is it possible to virtualize a mouse driver/device on clients side?

Answer (score 1):

In terminal type: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1243078

Comment: You should describe why this helps. what does this command actually do?